# Getting a kernel failure when trying to install Parrot OS (Linux) on VMware WS 10

Tags: linux, boot, installation, vmware, kernel-panic

I am using Windows 10 and I enabled the VT-x option from my BIOS and I have installed Windows 7 on VMware Workstation 10, and it just worked fine. But when I try to install Parrot OS (Linux) by choosing "install" in the menu,
it gives me this error:

> Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!

I tried live mode and it gave me the same error.

I installed Parrot and Kali Linux many times before on my old laptop and it worked fine and I never got this error before.

Here's the screen with the error:

[image: error screen]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the full text corresponding to the problem? It would be more helpful as the kernel panic message (attempting to kill the init process) can be a result of many things.

Comment: @RYOK Security Please “Join this community” (click the button that says that, or simply “Log In”) to merge your Information Security Stack Exchange account into Super User. You’ll then be able to [edit], comment on, and accept answers to this question.

Comment: @VarunNarravula: [Please don’t ask people to post photographs of text; ask them to post the *actual* text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216 "PSA: Please don’t post images of text") If the user does not have access to the text in a way that allows textual copy and paste, a screenshot may be acceptable. Actual *photographs* (i.e., with a camera) are the worst option.

Comment: So looks like the kernel wasn’t being loaded correctly by the VMware implementation. Have you tried checksumming the VM image you downloaded and comparing it with the given checksum on the Parrot OS website? If they are different, then you have to download it again because the file is not the same as the official VM image provided by Parrot and may have been corrupted by the download.